# Why is my button not clickable despite having an event handler?

Tags: c#, maui

After adding a Clicked event handler in the code behind, and adding it to my Button in XAML, the HandleClicked event handler never fires when tapping the button.

What have I done wrong to cause the Button.Clicked event not to fire?

MainPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp1.MainPage">

    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="25"
            Padding="30,0"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" BackgroundColor="#FFFFFF">
            <Image Source="project.png"
                   HeightRequest="400"
                   WidthRequest="500"
                   HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" IsAnimationPlaying="False"/>

            <Label Text="Welcome to Clime"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                FontSize="Title"
                FontAttributes="Bold"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                Margin="0,0,0,30" FontFamily="Poppins-Light" TextColor="#353535"/>
            
            <Label Text="Enter your zip code and explore precise local weather in your area"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                FontSize="Subtitle"
                FontAttributes="None"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                Margin="0,-50,0,0" FontFamily="Poppins-Light" TextColor="#B7B7B7" CharacterSpacing="-0.5"/>

            <Entry x:Name="EntryZipCode"
                Placeholder="Enter Zip Code"
                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                WidthRequest="400"
                HeightRequest="20"
                FontSize="Small"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                Margin="20"
                Keyboard="Numeric" TextColor="#000000" Opacity="100" PlaceholderColor="#B7B7B7" FontFamily="Poppins-Light"/>

            <Button x:Name="BtnShowTemp"
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                WidthRequest="400"
                HeightRequest="60"
                Text="Show Current Weather"
                FontSize="Medium"
                FontFamily="Poppins-Light"
                Padding="15"
                Clicked="BtnShowTemp_Clicked_1" BackgroundColor="#594a9e" CornerRadius="30" />

            


        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
namespace MauiApp1
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void BtnShowTemp_Clicked_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    string url = $"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip={EntryZipCode.Text}&appid=&units=imperial";
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                await DisplayAlert("API Error", ex.Message, "Close");
            }
        }

       
    }
}
```

I tried rewriting the entire code, but I'm having the same issue. The button isn't clickable when it's supposed to be.

Comment: how do you know the event handler is not being called?

Comment: When running the code, after typing up the zip code and pressing the button, the program should stop and give me a url link to type into a browser that gives me info. When trying out my program, the button doesn't do anything.

Comment: There is nothing in your event handler code that does that.  It just requests a url and then does nothing with the result

Comment: Ahh, I just tested it using a displayalert. You are correct, it does work. The only issue I'm facing now is that according to my Professor, my code it suppose to have a breakpoint on HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url); and if I hover over the string url, it should give me a url to copy and paste into a web browser. It isn't doing that. I've looked at his example code and it looks like everything it correct, so I don't know what I did what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Yes, it should, but the debugger can be fickle sometimes.  You can also use the watch or immediate window when you hit the breakpoint to evaluate an expression, or just use `Console.Writeline()` to write it to the log

Comment: Do you know how to insert a beakpoint? Click in the left margin on the line you want to break.